# React Material UI 2 TableRows in one loop error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm making my first project in React and I have a problem rendering my table correctly. 
What I'm trying to achieve is this;

[image]

The green brackets are what's inside my loop. The problem is that REACT says I need a wrapper for my TableRow-elements. I would assume my wrapper is my TableBody. The return method of my table looks like this;

```
return(
            <div className="container">
                <Table>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            {this.props.headers.map((el, i) => 
                                <TableCell key={i+3}>{el}</TableCell>
                            )}
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                    {this.props.data.map((element, j) => 
                        <TableRow key={j+j+j+j+j}>
                            <TableCell key={element["Nr"]+j}>{element["Nr"]}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell key={element["Description"]+j}>{element["Description"]}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell key={element["Reference"]+j}>{element["Reference"]}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell key={element["Parameters"]+j}><FontAwesomeIcon data-index={j} className="font-awesome-icon info-icon" onMouseLeave={this.hideToolTip} onMouseEnter={this.showToolTip} icon={faInfoCircle} />
                                {toolTip[j]}
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow> !!REACT WON'T ACCEPT  THIS SECOND TABLEROW!! </TableRow>
                    )}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>

        </div>
        )
```

The error is the following;

Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment < >...< />?

What I've tried so far is wrap both TableRows of this loop in a parent TableRow, but Table rows cannot directly contains Table rows, of course.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Didn't try it, but you could try to wrap it with a `<React.Fragment>` element

Comment: You were right! Should be the answer instead of a comment. Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome ;) I posted it as comment, since I didn't verify it and was only guessing

Answer (score 1):

In react some things (almost everything) needs the same start and end tag to be valid, take a return for example, this is valid:

```
export default observer(() => {    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    )
})
```

This will reslut in a error

```
export default observer(() => {    
    return (
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <div>                
        </div>
    )
})
```

So what you can do is to use the `<React.Fragment>`tag around all code in your loop, or simply use a loop foreach block. This is valid

```
export default observer(() => {    
    return (
     <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <div>                
        </div>
     </React.Fragment>
    )
})
```

Your code with fragment

```
return(
            <div className="container">
                <Table>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            {this.props.headers.map((el, i) => 
                                <TableCell key={i+3}>{el}</TableCell>
                            )}
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                    {this.props.data.map((element, j) => 
                       <React.Fragment>
                        <TableRow key={j+j+j+j+j}>
                            <TableCell key={element["Nr"]+j}>{element["Nr"]}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell key={element["Description"]+j}>{element["Description"]}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell key={element["Reference"]+j}>{element["Reference"]}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell key={element["Parameters"]+j}><FontAwesomeIcon data-index={j} className="font-awesome-icon info-icon" onMouseLeave={this.hideToolTip} onMouseEnter={this.showToolTip} icon={faInfoCircle} />
                                {toolTip[j]}
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow> !!REACT WILL ACCEPT  THIS SECOND TABLEROW!! </TableRow>
                      </React.Fragment>
                    )}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>

        </div>
        )
```

Comment: Thank you. One small thing to add is, apparently the React.Fragment needs a unique key aswell. Other than that it's perfect, thanks!